# Firebase Functions user offline trigger

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I would like to update user's status info when he just lost the connection inside the app. But I cannot trigger when he lose connection with Firebase.

Here some of triggers:

```
onWrite(), //which triggers when data is created, destroyed, or changed in the Realtime Database.
onCreate(), //which triggers when new data is created in the Realtime Database.
onUpdate(), //which triggers when data is updated in the Realtime Database.
onDelete(), //which triggers when data is deleted from the Realtime Database.
```

So how to update user's status if he lost the connection? Any hint will be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will help you out: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.OnDisconnect

Create a onWrite event on lets say /disconnected/{user}

Assuming you are coding in Swift, you could use the following code:

```
dataRef.child("disconnected").onDisconnectUpdateChildValues(["uid" : user.uid])
//ofcourse change dataRef to your reference.
```

When the user disconnect -> Firebase executes the onDisconnect -> onWrite event get triggered.

Javascript:

```
ref.onDisconnect().update({onlineState: false,status: "I'm offline."})
```

Comment: Thank you so much, But if you'll add javascript code it will be helpful for me and others, thanks again!

Comment: @Sam I did! Happy coding.

Comment: I don't know about javascript, how should be the full function to detect ondisconnect, It should looks like this? https://i.gyazo.com/37af86fcf9ae7e086eccafba4f79fa14.png

Comment: @Sam I am sorry I only code in Swift... You could ask that question with a Javascript tag they can help you :)

Comment: Alright, I'll try to do it first and see if it will works, Thank you so much and have a nice day!

Comment: The link to the documentation doesn't work anymore